# delete temporary files in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, memory, temp-tables

I have a huge database of about 800GB. When I tried to run a query which groups certain variables and aggregates the result, it was stopping after running for a couple of hours. Postgres was throwing a message that disk space is full. After looking at the statistics I realized that the dB has about 400GB of temporary files. I believe these temp files where created while I was running the query. My question is how do I delete these temp files. Also, how do I avoid such problems - use cursors or for-loops to not process all the data at once? Thanks.

I'm using Postgres 9.2

Comment: How do you "look at statistics" and what "temporary files" are you speaking off? Temporary tables are deleted at the end of a session, so closing your session and then opening a new session should do the trick.

Comment: The above should possibly be moved to the answer.

Comment: The most probable cause is a (unintended) Carthesian product.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The temporary files that get created in `base/pgsql_tmp` during query execution will get deleted when the query is done. You should not delete them by hand.
These files have nothing to do with temporary tables, they are use to store data for large hash or sort operations that would not fit in `work_mem`.

Make sure that the query is finished or canceled, try running `CHECKPOINT` twice in a row and see if the files are still there. If yes, that's a bug; did the PostgreSQL server crash when it ran out of disk space?

If you really have old files in `base/pgsql_tmp` that do not get deleted automatically, I think it is safe to delete them manually. But I'd file a bug with PostgreSQL in that case.

There is no way to avoid large temporary files if your execution plan needs to sort large result sets or needs to create large hashes. Cursors won't help you there. I guess that with *for-loops* you mean moving processing from the database to application code – doing that is usually a mistake and will only move the problem from the database to another place where processing is less efficient.

Change your query so that it doesn't have to sort or hash large result sets (check with `EXPLAIN`). I know that does not sound very helpful, but there's no better way. You'll probably have to do that anyway, or is a runtime of several hours acceptable for you?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using some custom aggregate functions, which I believe is creating large temporary files. The EXPLAIN shows that the aggregate function is sorting the data. I was wondering if there is a way to avoid sorts in aggregate functions. I'm not interested in the order of the results. Runtime of several hours is acceptable because this is a one-time processing of data but the large temp files are stopping the query execution. Thanks.

Comment: With *custom aggregate functions* you mean third party C functions? It's hard to answer that question without knowing how that aggregate function is defined and what the `EXPLAIN` output looks like.

Comment: I learned today, before PostgreSQL14, PostgreSQL clears pgsql_tmp only at startup. If someone come here with this problem, you can clear pgsql_tmp with restarting database.

Comment: @YavuzSelim Note that that can be relevant only after a server crash, because otherwise no temporary files will be left behind.

Comment: I am having a similar issue wherein old, and obviously orphaned temp files are accumulating and taking up a lot of space. I am nearly positive it is happening because of a server crashed that is induced because of a misbehaving extension (pgsync). Restarting the server isn't the best solution to this for a production environment. How can I confidently identify which temp files are safe to delete?

Comment: @AlexiTheodore Any file that is older than your oldest transaction can go. An exception is if you are using `WITH HOLD` cursors, which survive a transaction.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the confidence boost / help. I thought that was the case, but didn't want to take any risks. For future reference, is there a way to get a list of what temp files are being used (v13) so as to eliminate all possible doubt?

Comment: @AlexiTheodore Not that I know of.