# Open temp files in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

We have about 200 GB files inside `temp` folder in PostgreSQL. And it's time to clear it but I'm not sure is it safe or not. Thats why I want to look at these files first. File names look like: `pgsql_tmp644088.0`. How can I open and read them? With Notepad I can only see some symbols, for example:       `ЎҐЖ№T ipadinstagram%instagram_stories       j‹74`. What is your reccomendations?

Comment: The files are in a binary format, you can't easily open them in a meaningful way in an editor.  Would direct you at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39198380/delete-temporary-files-in-postgresql) and it's answers as they're a symptom of something else going on

Answer (score 1):

Simply restart PostgreSQL, and it should delete all the temporary files that were left behind.

Normally, temporary files don't exist longer than the duration of a query. Check for long running queries.

Answer (score 0):

Do not manually delete temp file. As a first step i would check what operations are using temp files. You have some options to enable logs on queries writing to temp files:

1. Enable log_tmp_files

or

2. Use [pgbadger](https://github.com/darold/pgbadger)
3. Query table Pg_stat_statements, as follows:

   SELECT interval '1 millisecond' * total_time AS total_exec_time,
   total_time / calls AS avg_exec_time_ms,
   temp_blks_written,
   query AS query
   FROM pg_stat_statements
   WHERE temp_blks_written > 0
   ORDER BY temp_blks_written DESC
   LIMIT 20;
4. Query pg_stat_database to give db level stats, as follows:

   select datname, temp_files , pg_size_pretty(temp_bytes) as temp_file_size  FROM   pg_stat_database order by temp_bytes desc;
5. Run EXPLAIN ANALYZE and compare work_mem size with values printed by explain analyze.

As a general recommendation set temp_file_limit to a value different than -1 (default).
Be sure to use correct indices to tune queries.
Tune work_mem (carefully).
Set statement_timeout to an optimal value.

**Please note:**
**Temp files are created when memory is not sufficient.**